# Error when trying to build my golang application in docker while using the mysql driver

Tags: docker, go, mysql-connector

I have a simple application that uses `github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql` to connect to a MySQL database and execute simple queries. This all works fine on my local machine, however when I try to build it using docker build I get the following output:

```
[+] Building 4.1s (9/10)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 104B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/golang:onbuild                                                  1.3s
 => [auth] library/golang:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 5.63kB                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/golang:onbuild@sha256:c0ec19d49014d604e4f62266afd490016b11ceec103f0b7ef44  0.0s
 => [2/2] COPY . /go/src/app                                                                                       0.1s
 => [3/2] RUN go-wrapper download                                                                                  2.0s
 => ERROR [4/2] RUN go-wrapper install                                                                             0.6s
------
 > [4/2] RUN go-wrapper install:
#8 0.465 + exec go install -v
#8 0.535 github.com/joho/godotenv
#8 0.536 github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
#8 0.581 # github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
#8 0.581 ../github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/driver.go:88: undefined: driver.Connector
#8 0.581 ../github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/driver.go:99: undefined: driver.Connector
#8 0.581 ../github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/nulltime.go:36: undefined: sql.NullTime
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c go-wrapper install]: exit code: 2
```

My go version is up to date and I am using the following dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:onbuild
```

To my knowledge this should `go get` all the packages it requires. I've also tried it this way:

```
FROM golang:onbuild
RUN go get "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
```

This had the same output.
Note that in my code I import the package like this:

```
import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
```

I also use other packages from github, these seem to work fine.

Comment: can you share your entire Dockerfile here

Comment: The only thing my dockerfile contains is `FROM golang:onbuild`

Comment: so, there is no command to copy your project's source code into docker build image?

Comment: I am using `docker build .` to build the entire directory containing both the dockerfile and the source code. I've managed to build a working container like this before and I believe the issue to be with the SQL driver

Comment: your go file is compiled using some command, this command might be in your docker file, or in the base image which is used by docker file `golang:onbuild`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Docker community has generally been steering away from the Dockerfile `ONBUILD` directive, since it makes it very confusing what will actually happen in derived images (see the various comments around "is that really the entire Dockerfile?").  If you [search Docker Hub for the `golang:onbuild` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/golang/?tab=tags&page=1&name=onbuild) you'll discover that this is Go 1.7 or 1.8; Go modules were introduced in Go 1.11.

You'll need to update to a newer base image, and that means writing out the Dockerfile steps by hand.  For a typical Go application this would look like

```sh
FROM golang:1.18 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY ./ ./
RUN go build -o myapp .

FROM ubuntu:20.04
COPY --from=build /app/myapp /usr/local/bin
CMD ["myapp"]
```

(In the final stage you may need to `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ...` a MySQL client library or other tools.)

Comment: This does the trick for me, I didn't realize the `golang:onbuild` was this outdated. Thanks!